# A problem occurred evaluating project ':app' java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError (no error message)

Tags: react-native

I am creating a react native app but get this error while running it.

- Where:
  Build file '/home/barokah/www/PCP/pcp-csd-mobile-apps/android/app/build.gradle' line: 1
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

  > java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError (no error message)
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 11s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file '/home/barokah/www/PCP/pcp-csd-mobile-apps/android/app/build.gradle' line: 1
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

  > java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError (no error message)
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 11s

```
at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:607:13)
at execFileSync (child_process.js:627:13)
at runOnAllDevices (/home/barokah/www/PCP/pcp-csd-mobile-apps/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:74:39)
at buildAndRun (/home/barokah/www/PCP/pcp-csd-mobile-apps/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/index.js:158:41)
at then.result (/home/barokah/www/PCP/pcp-csd-mobile-apps/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/index.js:125:12)
at <anonymous>
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)
```

error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

I've tried all instructions here
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment

but still, get the same error

I expected it can run normally, if anyone can help, please help. Thank you.